# Las ventanas de configuración de Android Studio aparecen como pestañas y no responden

Tags: android-studio, macos

Tengo instalado Android Studio 4.1 en una macbook pro con BigSur en un disco ssd externo, todo bien, el único problema que cuando tengo abierto un proyecto y por ejemplo deseo pegar una imagen en Drawable salta la ventana en nueva pestaña y no responde. Por ejemplo voy a configuración de proyecto para cambiar algo, igualmente todo sale en una nueva pestaña y los botones no responden. Todo esto desde que instale Android Studio 4.1. Antes no e tenido este problema.

Desinstale varias veces y instalado todo de nuevo borrando incluso las configuraciones y nada.

Alguien le a pasado esto, es algún problema de configuración o de la versión5.1 ?

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene siendo MacOS Big Sur, android Studio 4.1 no esta optimizado. habra que esperar una actualización o en todo caso la version 4.2.

La solución por el momento es fijar la siguiente configuración en tu MAC para desactivar las pestañas (aunque eso afecta a todo el sistema)

`Preferencias de sistema > General > Preferir pestañas "nunca" al abrir documentos`

[image: configuración]